# OCIServerAttach() hangs forever

Tags: c, linux, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I have observed quite some time that the connection attempt to an Oracle server using OCI library hangs forever and I am not able to find a way out to cancel the hung session. Even Ctrl+C doesn't work.

Do we have an option to call OCIServerAttach API in non-blocking mode or is there is an option that can be used to timeout the OCIServerAttach call?

Please note that the OCI version I am using is 11.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Net can be configured to limit the connection establishment time.  The available options have been enhanced in various versions. Oracle 11.2 is 10 years old!!

For recent versions (check the manual for your version), you could create a sqlnet.ora file with options like [`SQLNET.OUTBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT`](https://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=dblatest&id=GUID-0857C817-675F-4CF0-BFBB-C3667F119176) or [`TCP.CONNECT_TIMEOUT`](https://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=dblatest&id=GUID-A51F20BC-6493-49A5-A022-D4FBA1905AE5), or use [`CONNECT_TIMEOUT`](https://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=dblatest&id=GUID-F20C5DC5-C2FC-4145-9E4E-345CCB8148C7) in a tnsnames.ora file.  Search for 'connect_timeout' in that manual for other choices.

If you use 19c client libraries (that, by the way, will connect to Oracle DB 11.2 or later) then you can even use a timeout option in an [Easy Connect](https://download.oracle.com/ocomdocs/global/Oracle-Net-19c-Easy-Connect-Plus.pdf) connection string like `"mydbmachine.example.com/orclpdb1?connect_timeout=15"`

Comment: Thank you Christopher for the response. It was really helpful. Other than time out, do we also have an option to call OCIServerAttach API in non-blocking mode?

The OCI programming manual recommends to set "OCI_ATTR_NONBLOCKING_MODE" attribute of the server handle to call OCI functions in non-blocking mode, but can we do that for OCIServerAttach()?

Further, is it possible or safe to have a user-defined signal handler to terminate a function call to OCIServerAttach()?

Comment: I asked around and it seems OCIServerAttach is always blocking.  An Oracle Net person might be able to answer the signal handling question.